Primeng Ultima - integration with Angular standalone
I have created an Angular app (via jhipster), and I am trying to integrate the Ultima primeng template.
The issue I have is that my Angular app uses standalone components whereas Ultima doesn't to use such components.
Is Ultima compatible with Angular 18+ and standalone architecture ?
